# Jasper report - the first line from a list is not displayed

Tags: jasper-reports, javabeans

I use Jasper reports 6.17 and I made a list in Jasper Studio.

The list has only 2 items named "test1" and "test2" but only one is displayed and I don't know why. The resulting PDF displays only "test2", why is "test1" missing?
If I add 10 items the first line will be missing.

The jrxml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="LIST" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="e7ee8129-93f1-4ca4-ba39-4b3d41bc1dd1">
    <subDataset name="Item" uuid="e9567b90-2de8-4e93-bad6-f67f0139e348">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="178" y="31" width="100" height="30" uuid="3c38bb5e-a468-491b-8a3c-e04104fd93fe"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Item" uuid="16e7dfb2-6696-4eb8-98a9-c590e4c9fc28">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="100">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="2ff6723b-b461-420c-b233-ac3963d3b41b"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

And the java files are:

```
public class JasperTestList2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            List<Item> its = new ArrayList<>();
            
            Item i1 = new Item();
            i1.setName("test1");
            its.add(i1);
            
            Item i2 = new Item();
            i2.setName("test2");
            its.add(i2);
            
            JRBeanCollectionDataSource itemsJRBean = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(its);

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("JasperReports/LIST.jasper", null, itemsJRBean);

            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("JasperList.pdf"));
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outputStream);
        } catch (JRException | FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JasperTestList2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

public class Item {
    private String name;
    public void setName(String name){this.name = name;}
    public String getName()         {return name;}
}
```

Comment: When you provide your datasource you have 2 entries.  The DETAIL band pulls the first entry out of this (ITEM1).  You then pass the same datasource into the List, when the list pulls the `NEXT()` item, this is(ITEM2).  There is no way (or at least I know of) to rewind a datasource when doing this.

Comment: So I guess the detail band pulls automatically the first item, there is nothing I can do to prevent it. Thank you, I guess some of my text in the answer I posted is no longer necessary.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, there may be some custom stuff you can do.  But in the grand scheme of things, you probably don't actually want to.  It would be better to apply the list as a FIELD within the first Datasource entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a great answer, I get it, but I can't format it in comments.

1. What you're doing.

```
datasource = [
   Item1,  <-- detail band next()
   Item2   <-- list datasource next()
]
```

2. What you're doing now.

```
parameter(item) = [
   Item1,  <-- list datasource next()
   Item2   <-- list datasource next()
],
datasource =
```

3. What you probably want to do.

```
datasource = [
   items = [  <-- main datasource next()
       item1, <-- list datasource next()
       item2  <-- list datasource next()
]
```

Obviously you need to work out the objects for your `JRBeanCollectionDatasource` but you want them to look like that.

```
public class ReportItem {
   private List<String> items;
}
```

Then building out a `List<ReportItem>` that you pass into the Datasource would work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but I still don't know why the original code is not working fine.

The solution is to change the dataset from

- "Use another connection"  = $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE} to
- "Use a JRDatasource expression" = $P{Item}. I also created a new parameter named Item of type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource

In the code, I've set the new parameter: parameters.put("Item", itemsJRBean);

So instead of giving the JRDataSource in the last parameter of fillReport I transmitted the JRDataSource in the second parameter. In the first solution it seems that something moves the cursor in the dataSource to the second record, I don't know what and why, this problem remains, I just circumvented it.

```
public static JasperPrint fillReport(String sourceFileName, Map<String, Object> params, JRDataSource dataSource)
```

The jrxml is now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.16.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.16.0-48579d909b7943b64690c65c71e07e0b80981928  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="LIST" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="e7ee8129-93f1-4ca4-ba39-4b3d41bc1dd1">
    <subDataset name="Item" uuid="e9567b90-2de8-4e93-bad6-f67f0139e348">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="Item" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="178" y="31" width="100" height="30" uuid="3c38bb5e-a468-491b-8a3c-e04104fd93fe"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Item" uuid="86c960dc-0b5e-41d6-a57e-07e1a638a2d6">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{Item}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="100">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="2ff6723b-b461-420c-b233-ac3963d3b41b"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

And the java file is now:

```
public class JasperTestList2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            List<Item> its = new ArrayList<>();
            
            Item i1 = new Item();
            i1.setName("test1");
            its.add(i1);
            
            Item i2 = new Item();
            i2.setName("test2");
            its.add(i2);

            Item i3 = new Item();
            i3.setName("test3");
            its.add(i3);
            
            JRBeanCollectionDataSource itemsJRBean = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(its);
            
            Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            parameters.put("Item", itemsJRBean);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("JasperReports/LIST.jasper", parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());

            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("JasperList.pdf"));
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outputStream);
        } catch (JRException | FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JasperTestList2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```